# Vuetify: Find width of v-menu content

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a custom v-menu. The content section is a mega menu panel that is built with a v-container, v-row and v-column. Since the mega menu panel is relatively wide I'm trying to add a visual indicator connecting the menu button to the panel. For positioning purposes I need to know the width of the button and content panel plus the absolute position of both as well.
`this.$refs.menuButton.$el.clientWidth` returns the correct value but
`this.$refs.menuPanel.$el.clientWidth` returns a value of zero.

I'm presuming this has something to do with the fact that the panel isn't visible until the menu item is clicked?  How would I go about getting the width of the panel and it's position? Simplified code below. I tried adding a watch to trigger on menu opening but that also returned a zero.

```
<v-menu offset-y open-on-hover>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn v-on="on" :ripple="false"ref="menuButton">MENU BUTTON TITLE</v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-container ref="menuPanel">
      <v-row>
        <v-col
          v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than finding the width of the menu content, can you try using the `min-width / max-width` and `nudge-bottom` properties of v-menu to manage the position and width of the panel relative to the button - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-min-width